# Database setup and design for 15 questions game - PostgreSQL and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I am working on a small game where people have the ability to create 15 question quizzes. I am struggling to figure out how to structure my database for the best optimization.  The questions each have a point value assigned to them (same kind of structure as who wants to be a millionaire). I am debating whether to keep everything in the same table or to separate the game from the questions (or anything else if there is a more efficient method).

**Strategy 1:**
Creating columns for each in the Game table.  So there would be a column for title, 100 point question, 100 point answer, 200 point question, 200 point answer, etc..

**Strategy 2:**
Creating a new table for questions.  Each question belongs to a game, and is assigned the point value, and an answer

**Strategy 3:**
Create many tables for each point value.  There would be a 100 table, a 200 table, etc.  The columns would then be only the question or answer.

Are any of these the most efficient way of implementing this game?   I am trying to learn how database setup can effect speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time efficiency is not as important as normalisation. You should have a separate games, questions and answers tables. Your models would look something like:

```
class Game
  has_many :questions
end

class Question
  belongs_to :game
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Comment: each game has one 100point question one 200 point question, one 500 point question, etc (20 totals).  Would it be good to do `has_one :100question`, `has_one :200 question`?

Comment: or would it be better to do it like your comment, but with scopes in the model

Comment: @DavidMckee it would be better to assign points to each question, and, yes, use scopes. You can even add validations to ensure you only have one question per point-level.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Damien Roche's answer but to add to it here is how I would structure your Schema:

```
create_table "Game" do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "description"
  t.integer  "user_id"    # if you want to keep track of who created it
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "Question" do |t|
  t.string   "description"
  t.integer  "points"
  t.integer  "game_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "Answer" do |t|
  t.string   "description"
  t.integer  "question_id"
  t.integer  "game_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

You may want to add a separate model (and corresponding table in your database) to keep track of an instance of the game being played (called a `GameRound` or something like that). It would look like this in its game_round.rb file:

```
class GameRound < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user      # the person playing the game
```

(You could add a model that tracks the answer to each question, or add an attribute in your database that keeps track of the same thing in a string).
The schema for `GameRound` could be this:

```
create_table "GameRound" do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"   # player
  t.integer  "game_id"   # id of the game being played
  t.integer  "score"     # accumulation of points
  t.string   "answers"   # a string of the answers to each question ex: "a,c,a,b,d"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```